# Updating a table before Insert causes warning on insert and incorrect value added to the table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am attempting to create a trigger that will automatically fill in the time difference between to different times entered into the database.

When using the trigger below I receive errors listed below and the hoursworked field always ends up with ".99" after the trigger executes. I tested the timediff function in SQL without setting it up via a trigger and I was able to generate the correct results I am looking for. I don't understand why this causes an error when I can get the right data testing the same SQL cmd.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `AddHoursWorkedBeforeInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `TimeSheetRequests`
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
SET new.hoursworked = timediff(new.endtime,new.starttime);
end
```

After I insert values into 'TimeSheetRequests' these errors are displayed.

1 row inserted.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'hoursworked' at row 1
Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'hoursworked' at row 1

Comment: So... what is the data type of `hoursworked`.

Comment: Its a float(2,2) because I didnt want someone to put in more that the number of hours you can work in a day and i only want to keep accuracy of hoursworked to 2 decimal places.

Comment: In that case you should probably look at what [timediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) returns (you can run `select timediff(now(),date_sub(now(), interval 44 day))` in your MySQL client).

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'hoursworked' at row 1
Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'hoursworked' at row 1
```

The value you were trying to set is too large for the datatype of the given column hoursworked and also since the length of the value you were trying to set for the given column is higher than the given maximum value.

Solution is to change the datatype as required and to increase the max value as required to avoid truncation.